# Recommended patterns for hooking up context providers in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a React application, using multiple context providers to pass down data to components, similar to the following (simplified) code.

Here is an example of a context provider, which is consuming the context from another provider:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useAuth} from './auth-context'

const UserContext = React.createContext()

function UserProvider(props) {
  const {
    data: {user},
  } = useAuth()
  return <UserContext.Provider value={user} {...props} />
}

function useUser() {
  const context = React.useContext(UserContext)
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`useUser must be used within a UserProvider`)
  }
  return context
}

export {UserProvider, useUser}
```

Here are the nested context providers, exported together:

```
import React from 'react'
import {AuthProvider} from './auth-context'
import {UserProvider} from './user-context'

function AppProviders({children}) {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <UserProvider>{children}</UserProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
}

export default AppProviders
```

Here are the providers hooked up to the application. `<App />` contains all the application components:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'
import AppProviders from './context'

ReactDOM.render(
  <AppProviders>
    <App />
  </AppProviders>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Is there a recommended pattern for providing your React application with access to multiple context providers? Is it this?

Secondary question: When context providers are *not* dependent upon another, does that impact your recommendation? For example, if the `UserProvider` in the above example did not rely on the `AuthProvider` and instead looked something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import userClient from './userClient'

const UserContext = React.createContext()

function UserProvider(props) {
  const [ user, setUser ] = React.useState(null);
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user} {...props} />
  );
}

function useUser() {
  const context = React.useContext(UserContext)

  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`useUser must be used within a UserProvider`)
  }
  return context
}

function loadUser() {
  return userClient.loadUser().then(data => {
    setUser(data);
  });
}


export {UserProvider, useUser, loadUser}
```

In this (second) scenario, are there cons for keeping `UserProvider` nested inside `AuthProvider` vs. separating the providers and where they are rendered in the component hierarchy?